# Execute Mysql query variable in procedure

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add dynamically columns to a table.

I get a SQL syntax error while trying to do execute a statement inside the following procedure. :

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_collabs;
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE sp_collabs(IN StartDate DATE, IN EndDate DATE) 
    BEGIN 

        DECLARE CurrentDate DATE;
        DECLARE n INT;
        DECLARE i INT;
        DECLARE tempColumnName VARCHAR(255);
        DECLARE queryAddDateColumn varchar(255);
        SET @CurrentDate = StartDate;
        SET @n = 0;
        SET @i = 0;
        SET @tempColumnName = '';
        SET @queryAddDateColumn = '';

        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _tmpUniqueDates;
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _tmpFinal;
        CREATE TABLE _tmpUniqueDates (`uniqueDate` DATETIME);
        CREATE TABLE _tmpFinal (`Collaborateur` varchar(255));

        label1: WHILE @CurrentDate <= EndDate DO

            INSERT IGNORE INTO _tmpUniqueDates select DATE_FORMAT(@CurrentDate, "%Y-%m-%d"); 

            SET @CurrentDate = DATE_ADD(@CurrentDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);

        END WHILE label1;

        ##Créer la table finale
           #Créer une table avec les colonnes pour toutes les dates.
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM _tmpUniqueDates INTO n;
        SET i=0;
        WHILE i<n DO 
            SET @tempColumnName = (SELECT uniqueDate FROM _tmpUniqueDates LIMIT i, 1);
            SET @queryAddDateColumn = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE _tmpFinal ADD COLUMN' 
            ,DATE_FORMAT(@tempColumnName, "%Y-%m-%d"),' VARCHAR(255);');
            #SELECT CONCAT('',@queryAddDateColumn);
            PREPARE stmt FROM @queryAddDateColumn; 
            EXECUTE stmt; 
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
            SET i = i + 1;  
        END WHILE;

        SELECT * FROM _tmpFinal;
    END//
    DELIMITER ;

    CALL sp_collabs('2020-03-01', '2020-03-31');
```

If I do a select on the query, it seems correct: `'ALTER TABLE _tmpFinal ADD COLUMN 2020-03-01 VARCHAR(255);'`

How can I get my statement executed?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think column names can start with a number or contain -(minus) unless quoted (backticked)

Comment: ok this was it. Thanks! Now it works:    set @queryAddDateColumn = concat("ALTER TABLE _tmpFinal ADD COLUMN column_",DATE_FORMAT(@tempColumnName, "%Y%m%d")," VARCHAR(255);");